# Excel: Show matching content in cell

Tags: excel, list, validation, range, cell

A bit of a noob with Excel. I’m trying to help my department by making an assignment front sheet that will insert data based on the selections made.

So far I have created a drop down list that will check for unit number (data validation -> list -> named range), which in turn adds the unit name (index and match named ranges) and shows only available criteria linked to that unit (data validation -> list -> indirect). The problem that I am having is getting the criteria descriptor to show up in the cell next to the chosen criteria.

I don't want to be using VBA or any macros as the staff and IT Techs are paranoid about security. A formula based solution would be great.

It probably makes more sense if you [download](http://1drv.ms/19H8O7r)(updated link) my spreadsheet.

Thanks

AC

Comment: In its current form you probably don't need VBA. Macros can be abused but I think you can password protect your code, and possibly digitally sign it to ensure it's not modified maliciously.

Comment: password protection I will do before its given to the rest of the staff :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I've understood the data in your sheet correctly, you can use a `VLOOKUP`

In Cell D17: `=IF(ISBLANK(C17)=FALSE,VLOOKUP(C17,Data!$L$2:$M$14,2,FALSE))`

In Cell D18: `=IF(ISBLANK(C18)=FALSE,VLOOKUP(C18,Data!$L$2:$M$14,2,FALSE))`

In Cell D19: `=IF(ISBLANK(C19)=FALSE,VLOOKUP(C19,Data!$L$2:$M$14,2,FALSE))`

etc.. for as many rows you have.

I'm not sure if the extra columns are meant to be populated too using the data in your data sheet, but its fairly simple to adjust the VLOOKUP to do this.

**Update**
My code above doesn't work as I didn't look at the validation stuff. I've edited your example work book, and it should now display the correct details.
The colours in the data sheet are just to show the name'd ranges I've used.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10316127/2015-Assignment_.xlsx

Comment: i've populated criteria descriptor for unit 2, do I simply just extend the range for the cells so it will check those as well?

Comment: My code needs to be adjusted as I didn't look into your validation, currently it is hard coded to only show the unit one descriptions regardless.

Comment: This is not correct , its always looking up column unit 1

Comment: Thats what my comment says :)

Answer (score 0):

I Think your actually looking for this

```
=INDEX(Unit1_Criteria_Descriptor,MATCH($C17,INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE($J$7," ",""),0)))
```

Your unit in C17 has a space "Unit 2" so i am using SUBSTITUTE to remove before i pass it to INDIRECT so that the MATCH is looking up the right column